# Therefore or thus

Tags: word-difference, writing

What is the difference in meaning of **therefore** and **thus**?
And which one would better fit in this context:

> It enables parties to obtain a judgement on specific issues of their case without the need to commence  proceedings on the merits in their personal injury dispute. **Therefore**, parties will not be confronted with the disadvantages of conventional trials; instead, after obtaining a decision from the partial dispute judge, they can resume their negotiations and pursue a settlement.

or

> It enables parties to obtain a judgement on specific issues of their case without the need to commence  proceedings on the merits in their personal injury dispute. **Thus**, parties will not be confronted with the disadvantages of conventional trials; instead, after obtaining a decision from the partial dispute judge, they can resume their negotiations and pursue a settlement.

Or do you have better suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They mean the same. I don't think there's a preference when choosing *thus* or *therefore*, is there? You can also place them in the middle of the clause by using commas, like (...),*therefore/thus,* (...).

Comment: @Taco- Did you mean to say, **"impartial** dispute judge"? A "partial" dispute judge would be of little value in mediation, unless "partial dispute judge" is a formal title with which I am simply unfamiliar.

Comment: @Taco - Refer to this and see if it answers your question: https://painintheenglish.com/case/4452/

Comment: @MarkHubbard in Dutch law we have something called Partial Dispute Proceedings and we call a judge that hears those types of cases a partial dispute judge. So, that's probably the reason for your confusion :)

Comment: @Taco- Excellent! Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @stangdon Your linked article seems to incorrectly imply that the two words always have different meanings. But the most common sense of *thus* is synonomous with *therefore.*

Comment: This question is off-topic because the primary question should be answerable by consulting a dictionary. Otherwise, include more detail explaining why you still have questions after looking up the words.